# ERROR MESSAGE: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted (Invalid viewstate)

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, iis-6

I have two servers on **IIS6** where load balancing is done by a load balancing hardware. When a response is provided `Server 1` and the **postback** is handled by `Server 2` it always gets an error `The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted` and underneath `Invalid viewstate` on **almost** every **postback** when requests are handled by alternative servers. *If I turn off one of the server then it seems to be working fine.*

I have checked the `decryptionKey` and `validationKey` are both **exactly** same on the both server deployment, and also wth `enableEventValidation="false"` and `enableViewStateMac="false"`. There was no luck with all sorts of solutions available provided by Google :P

Please check the stack trace below where `exception` occurs at `HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load()` followed by `Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()`.

```
[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
    Client IP: 192.168.5.21
    Port: 60042
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1
    ViewState: {VIEWSTATE DATA}

[HttpException (0x80004005): The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.]
   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) +118
   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowViewStateError(Exception inner, String persistedState) +13
   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +222
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() +107
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +43
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6230
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +247
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +79
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +23
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +111
   OrderJourneyDefault.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\x\Default.aspx.cs:350
   ASP.toj_application_orderjourney_default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\82a64fa9\62e4fa0\App_Web_31vcm2al.0.cs:0
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +406
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +76
```

**NOTE:** There's no AJAX/Javascript related things to mess up my application.

Thanks in advance.
Munim